# Make systemd reload only single openvpn process and not the whole group

Tags: systemd, openvpn

I'm running several openvpn instances on my server with debian stable; as well some clients as a server instance. Right now, when one of these instances fails, systemd seems to kill and restart the whole group of processes:

```
May 27 12:09:44 tritone systemd[1]: openvpn@client_uk.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
May 27 12:09:44 tritone systemd[1]: Unit openvpn@client_uk.service entered failed state.
May 27 12:10:01 tritone systemd[1]: Stopping OpenVPN connection to client_rhode...
May 27 12:10:01 tritone systemd[1]: Starting OpenVPN connection to client_uk...
May 27 12:10:01 tritone systemd[1]: Stopping OpenVPN connection to client_ukraine...
May 27 12:10:01 tritone systemd[1]: Stopping OpenVPN connection to server_udp...
May 27 12:10:01 tritone systemd[1]: Stopping OpenVPN service...
May 27 12:10:01 tritone systemd[1]: Starting OpenVPN service...
May 27 12:10:01 tritone systemd[1]: Started OpenVPN service.
...
```

This is as well undesired as superfluous imho. Restarting the single failed service would suffice. This is the systemd config from `/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/openvpn.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=OpenVPN service
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=/bin/true
ExecReload=/bin/true
WorkingDirectory=/etc/openvpn

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I have seen configs, where ExecReload had been set to `kill -HUP $MAINPID`, and also my server seems to do this, as systemctl status says:

```
  Process: 5893 ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
```

So what I don't understand, where is this kill command defined, if the systemd config ExecReload actually says otherwise? Also, why is the service getting restarted, even if `Type=oneshot` is defined? Am I looking at the right file at all?

And how should the restart command look like? Kill won't work, as the process is supposedly dead already.

**Edit:** I found `/lib/systemd/system-generators/openvpn-generator` and `/lib/systemd/system/openvpn@.service` now, nevertheless, it remains unclear, when they get run or executed. The generator seems to fail, as none of the links actually got created, probably due to selinux restrictions. Nevertheless, this file seems to be used for init. So I wonder, why is the dummy file `/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/openvpn.service` created at all?

Comment: Could you provide the output of the following commands: $ systemctl -t service | grep openvpn and the output of $ systemctl cat <....>.service for each line from the previous command?

Comment: Much of this is answered at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/378749/ and at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/206058/ .

Answer (score 1):

If you use CONFIGNAME as your config file name for your `.conf` file you could try

```
systemctl restart openvpn@CONFIGNAME.service
```

Comment: This works with Debian.

Comment: It's not about restarting by hand, but about the automatic restarts of the whole group when a single one crashes.

Comment: It looks to me like a misconfiguration. It doesn't make sense to ask systemctl to restart openvpn because openvpn has it's own rules to restart instances when they fail. The only reason for systemctl to restart ovpn is if there is failures in dependencies like providing network.