# What are the alternatives for starting and stopping an openvpn configuration on Debian Jessie?

Tags: debian, systemd, openvpn, services

I had to change the openvpn configuration automatically and realized that the service was starting without any configuration. I assume that the openvpn service daemon was starting all configurations listed present in the `/etc/openvpn` directory.

After renaming the active configuration the new one I created did not run until I added it to the file `/etc/default/openvpn`. The point is the default one which was running before and whose configuration file I renamed was not in `/etc/default/openvpn` so I assuming that the previous one was configured somewhere else.

Are there any places where openvpn is configured besides `/etc/default/openvpn`?

Comment: Much of this is answered at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/378749/ .

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can have your configuration file in `/etc/openvpn/` and be able to enable, disable, start, and stop using `systemctl`.

```
systemctl start/stop openvpn@<configname>.service
```