# Why do some unit filenames end with @?

Tags: systemd, systemd-unit

Some applications, like ssh have a unit file that ends with @, like `ssh.service` and `ssh@.service`. They contain different contents, but I cannot understand what exactly is the difference in functionality or purpose.

Is it some naming convention I'm not aware of?

Comment: Relating https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/378824/117549

Answer (score 34, accepted):

As others have mentioned, it's a service template. In the specific case of `ssh@.service`, it's for invoking `sshd` only on-demand, in the style of classic `inetd` services.

If you expect SSH connections to be rarely used, and want to absolutely minimize `sshd`'s system resource usage (e.g. in an embedded system), you could disable the regular `ssh.service` and instead enable `ssh.socket`. The socket will then automatically start up an instance of `ssh@.service` (which runs `sshd -i`) whenever an incoming connection to TCP port 22 (the standard SSH port) is detected. This will slow down the SSH login process, but will remove the need to run `sshd` when there are no inbound SSH connections.

Answer (score 17):

It is a template: https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#Service%20Templates

It is instantiated by creating a link to `unit@instance.type` where the link source is `unit@.type`. The value of `instance` is available in the systemd unit file using `%i` or `%I`, and allows you to write a single unit config file that can be used multiple times with a parameter.

While the clearest systemd documentation for this is "Service Templates", you can template any unit type, as described in the systemd.unit(5) man page: https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html

Answer (score 12):

These are [service templates](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#Service%20Templates), designed to be instantiated with an argument (so the service is `template@argument`, running the `template@` service with the given argument). A single service definition can thus be used in different circumstances without needing any hard-coded specifics.

Typical instantiated services you’ll see are per-file system services such as the `systemd-fsck@` service, per-device `getty`s, the user manager for each user (`user@`), etc. They can be set up in the same way as non-templated services, using `systemctl enable` etc., but many are dynamically instantiated by other services.

Answer (score 7):

> Some unit names contain an `@` sign (e.g. `name@string.service`): this
>   means that they are [instances](http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/instances.html) of a template unit, whose actual file
>   name does not contain the `string` part (e.g. `name@.service`). `string` is
>   called the *instance identifier*, and is similar to an argument that is
>   passed to the template unit when called with the *systemctl* command: in
>   the unit file it will substitute the `%i` specifier. To be more
>   accurate, before trying to instantiate the `name@.suffix` template unit,
>   systemd will actually look for a unit with the exact
>   `name@string.suffix` file name, although by convention such a "clash"
>   happens rarely, i.e. most unit files containing an `@` sign are meant to
>   be templates.

[source](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/systemd)