# How does the systemd service naming convention work?

Tags: arch-linux, systemd

Arch Linux, systemd 252 (252.4-2-arch)

Doing:

```
systemctl status openvpn-server@server.service
```

Results in:

```
Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/openvpn-server@.service; enabled; preset: disabled)
```

However, running:

```
systemctl list-unit-files
```

Doesn't show the same name. It only shows:

```
openvpn-client@.service                    disabled        disabled
openvpn-server@.service                    indirect        disabled
```

Why is there this difference in naming convention, and why is it shown as disabled in this listing?

Comment: worth reading:  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/588629 https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/Systemd https://superuser.com/questions/393423

Comment: Also see [this article](https://fedoramagazine.org/systemd-template-unit-files/).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do some unit filenames end with @?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/588629/why-do-some-unit-filenames-end-with)